# Range error on Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").Value = "..."

Tags: excel, vba

I want to reference the activecell's location to add a title to the column in row 2 of the activecell's column.

I use `Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value =....` earlier in my code. I assume something like `Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").Value =....` would be valid.

I get an error

> Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed

on the line indicated below.

```
Dim found As Range
Set found = wsAbv.Range("B1:C93").Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not found Is Nothing Then
    For x = 1 To 93
        If ActiveCell.Value = wsAbv.Range("B" & (x)).Value Then
            ActiveCell.Value = wsAbv.Range("C" & (x)).Value
        End If
    Next
End If
ActiveCell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

'Getting 400 error at line below (Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed)

Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").ClearContents
Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").Value = "RIG"
Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").Interior.Color = RGB(183, 222, 232)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").Value = "QTY"
Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveCell.Column` returns a number, not a column letter. Use a R1C1 style instead.

```
Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column).ClearContents
```

instead of

```
Range((ActiveCell.Column) & "2").ClearContents
```